# How can I get a field value by it's index within a result set in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a stored procedure that is passing data into a crystal report. The result set looks something like this;

```
Product | Price
----------------
Apple   | 0.20
Pear    | 0.35
Orange  | 0.10
Tomato  | 0.23
```

I am displaying most of the data I need in the manner I require but cannot access a whole row of data, only individual fields.

I can access a particular price by using NthLargest function;

```
NthLargest (2,{up_Fruit;1.Price})
```

This returns the value of 0.23. I also want to get the associated product (Tomato)

How can this be done? I cannot find any way to connect a value in one field with another e.g. by getting the whole row.

Ultimately I'm wanting to show something like this in my report;

```
Second most expensive product is Tomato, it costs $0.23.
```

I can manage all the string formatting but cannot grab the product where the price is 0.23.

I'm using Crystal syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repalce your formula with below code:

```
Local Stringvar array x;
Local Numbervar i;
Local Stringvar display;

x:=x+({up_Fruit;1.Product} &"-"&ToText({up_Fruit;1.Price}));

join(x);

for i:=1 to UBound(x) do
(
if ToText(NthLargest (2,{up_Fruit;1.Price})) in x[i]
then
display:=x[i]
else
display:=""

);

"Second most expensive product is "& Split(display,"-")[1] & " , it costs "& Split(display,"-")[2]
```